# Override model save method to automatically store previous values of updated fields

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Say I have a number of probes which record values.  I want to set up Django models to represent the probes as well as the measurements they record.  So something like this would work:

```
class Probe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'<Probe: %s>' % self.name

class Observation(models.Model):
    probe = models.ForeignKey(Probe)
    obstime = models.DateTimeField()
    # the above field should be understood to represent the time in the world
    # represented by the measurement value recorded.  *not* the time at which
    # that value was written to the database.
    value = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('probe', 'obstime'), )

    def __unicode__(self):
        tup = (self.probe.name,
               self.obstime.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S'),
               '%0.2f' % self.value)
        return u'<Observation: %s @ %s = %s>' % tup
```

But beyond this, I would really like my database and app to be able to keep track of a bit more information.  In particular, I really want the `Observation` model to have 3 additional fields: `db_recording_time`, `previous_value`, `previous_db_recording_time`.  I want users to directly attempt to manipulate just the entries given above, but have the other fields behave automatically in the expected way.  I think this should be possible by overriding the `save` method on the `Observation` class, but I need some help!

So say a person comes back from the field and sits down at their computer at Noon on Jan5th.  They want to record some (never-before-entered) data indicating that ProbeA read 3.14 at 2AM on Jan1st.  I'd only want them to need to specify 3.14 and 2AMJan1st, but I'd want an observation to go into the DB with:

```
probe: ProbeA, 
obstime: 2AMJan1st, 
value: 3.14,
db_recording_time: NoonJan5th,
previous_value: Null, 
previous_db_reording_time: Null
```

Then, a couple hours later (2PMJan5th), that same person could look at their notebook and realize "oops, I misread the value in my notebook...it was really 2.14".  So I'd want them to (either using the admin or a Python console) call up the existing observation and correct the 3.14 to be a 2.14.  When they did that, I'd want the observation in the DB to show:

```
probe: ProbeA, 
obstime: 2AMJan1st, 
value: 2.14,
db_recording_time: 2PMJan5th,
previous_value: 3.14, 
previous_db_reording_time: NoonJan5th
```

I feel like this should be pretty straightforward with some combination of read-only fields in the Admin interface as well as some reasonable bit of overriding in the `save` method for the `Observation` class.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you think it would make more sense to add a foreign key to `self` in Observation model which refers to the observation taken earlier and then you don't need to duplicate these fields? Or, do you always want to refer to same observation? Because in that case you will only have the value from only the last observation and not the ones before that. But with the foreign key to `self` you could just store a series of observations and link them with each other.

Comment: That's a very cool idea. So the foreignkey into self would be called something like earlier_observation_draft. Makes sense. But if I do that, what is an efficient way to write the query that only returns the most recently entered value for a range of observation times for a given probe?  I.e. Before your enhancement, you could do Observation.objects.filter(probe=choseprobe) or Observation.objects.filter(probe=chosenprobe, obstime__gte=start, obstime__lte=end). But after the enhancement, that would get both the "currently considered right" values as well as the drafts that were corrected.

Comment: I added my comments as an answer and also tried to answer your other query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the old record from the database before saving:

```
recording_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
previous_value = models.FloatField(null=True, default=None)
previous_recording_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True, default=None)

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
         update_fields=None):
    try:  
        obj = Observation.objects.get(pk=self.pk)  
        # this is the record of this instance before editing
    except Observation.DoesNotExist:  # self.pk==None: this is a new Observation
        pass
    else:  #  this is indeed an update
        self.previous_value = obj.value
        previous_db_recording_time = obj.db_recording_time
    super(Observation, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using,
         update_fields=update_fields)
```

Now, nobody should ever have to manually set `recording_time`, `previous_value`, or `previous_recording_time`. So you can exclude those fields from the `ModelForm` that you use in `Observation`'s `Admin` class.

Answer (score 0):

As I suggested in comments, you could add a foreign key to `self` in Observation model which refers to the observation taken earlier and then you don't need to duplicate these fields e.g. `previous_value`, `previous_db_recording_time`.

```
class Observation(models.Model):
    ...
    prev_observation = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True)

    # you can also add a `is_recent` field to this model so you set it to True when its created
    is_recent = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So let's say you added 7 observations in a week `[o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7]` so for all these 7 `is_recentt` will be True.

And, you can get these observations as follows:

```
Observation.objects.filter(probe=chosenprobe, 
                           obstime__gte=start, obstime__lte=end,
                           is_recent=True)

# [o1, o2, o3, o4, o5, o6, o7]
```

Now, you corrected `o1`, `o3` and `o6` with `o8`, `o9` and `o10` so at this time you can set `is_recent` for `o1`, `o3` and `o6` to False.

And, then running the above query again will give you updated (recent) observations:

```
# [o2, o4, o5, o7, o8, o9, o10]
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I see it. Say I add a field on Observation called "recorded_at" and otherwise proceed as you suggest. In that case what is the way to get all observations for a given probe representing measurements taken in a given date range *but only showing the measurements for each timestamps that were most recently "recorded_at"*.   So say I make and record measurements representing data every day for a week. And then I go back and correct 3 of them.  So 10 observations in the db, representing 7 timestamps. How can I return just the 7 "most up to date" measurements?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the second part of your question. Please look at the updated answer.